# Modifying existing jQuery to animate buttons underneath slider slide-show

Tags: jquery, html, function, slideshow, uislider

Hopefully someone can help with this.

I am tweaking some code on a site (my jQuery knowledge is fairly rudimentary).

The previous coder is using an index to animate small squares under a slideshow (as well as lots of other bits and bobs.

An extract from the code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
SlideAreaData = [
// Our Commitment
    {
        Blurbs:[
            // 0 
            "We believe that businesses...",
            // 1
            "We can...",
            // 2
            "We will always..."
        ],
        SlideData:{// SlideNumber : [BlurbIndex,ListIndex,HighlightClass,SlideArrow]
            // Our Commitment landing
            0 :[0,0,'colour_blue','images/BlueArrow'],
            // Our Commitment
            1 :[1,1,'colour_blue','images/BlueArrow'],
            2 :[2,2,'colour_blue','images/BlueArrow']
        },
        Links:[[0,'background_blue'],[1,'background_blue'],[2,'background_blue'],[3,'']]// length of slides at end
    }
...
```

The slider function

```
 $('.slidebox_window').each(function(i,e){
    /*ContentArea*/
    var Blurbs = SlideAreaData[i].Blurbs;
    var SlideData = SlideAreaData[i].SlideData;
    var LinkData = SlideAreaData[i].Links;

    var SlideView = 0;
    var SlideBlurb = 0;
    var SlideLinkIndex = 0;
    var SlideHighlight = 'colour_blue';
    var _Startup = true;

    var SlideWindow = $(e);
    var Slides = $(e).children('.slidebox_slide');
    var Navlist = $(e).parentsUntil('#ContentArea').find('.slidebox_list > li');
    var BlurbDiv = $(e).parentsUntil('#ContentArea').find('.slidebox_blurb');
    var Progress = $(e).parentsUntil('#ContentArea').find('.slidebox_progress');

    var ButtonLeftImg = SlideWindow.find('.slidebox_nextz>img').eq(0);
    var ButtonRightImg = SlideWindow.find('.slidebox_nextz>img').eq(1);

    Navlist.each(function(i,e){
        $(e).click(function(event){
            SkipToSlide(LinkData[i][0]);
        });
    });

    var SkipToSlide = function(next,direction){
        if(direction != 1)
            direction = -1;
        if(next==SlideView || Slides.is(':animated') || BlurbDiv.is(':animated'))
            return;
        Slides.eq(next).css({'left':direction*640});
        Slides.filter(':eq('+SlideView+'),:eq('+next+')').animate({left:(direction==1?'-':'+')+'=640'},500,'easeOutElastic')
        HighlightSlide(next);
    };

    var HighlightSlide = function(next){
        if(next == SlideView /*&& !_Startup*/)
            return;
        info = SlideData[next];// 0:BlurbIndex, 1:LinkIndex, 2:HighlightClass

        size = LinkData[info[1]+1][0] - LinkData[info[1]][0];
        current = next - LinkData[info[1]][0];
        highlight = LinkData[info[1]][1];
        if(info[1] != SlideLinkIndex || _Startup){
            // Highlight active link
            Navlist.eq(SlideLinkIndex).removeClass(SlideHighlight);
            Navlist.eq(info[1]).addClass(info[2]);
            // Manage progress display
            if(size > 1){
                Progress.html(Array(size+1).join('<div></div>'));
                Progress.children().each(function(i,e){
                    $(e).on('click',function(){
                        SkipToSlide(LinkData[info[1]][0]+i);
                    }).css('cursor','pointer');
                });
            }else{
                Progress.html('');
            }
            SlideHighlight = info[2];
            SlideLinkIndex = info[1];
        }
        //SlideWindow.find('.slidebox_nextz>img').attr('src',info[3]);
        ButtonLeftImg.attr('src',info[3]+'L.png');
        ButtonRightImg.attr('src',info[3]+'R.png');
        Progress.children().removeClass(highlight).eq(current).addClass(highlight);

        if(SlideBlurb != info[0] /*|| _Startup*/){
            text = Blurbs[info[0]];
            test = BlurbDiv.clone().appendTo('#TestArea');//$('#TestArea').
            test.html(text).css({'height':'auto','width':BlurbDiv.outerWidth(true)});

            BlurbDiv.animate({opacity:0},250,function(){
                BlurbDiv.animate({height:test.height()},250,function(){
                    BlurbDiv.html(text);
                    BlurbDiv.animate({opacity:1},250,function(){
                        test.remove();
                    });
                });
            });
            SlideBlurb = info[0];
        }

        SlideView = next;
    };
    Highlighters[i] = HighlightSlide;
```

And then html under each slide is:

```
 <div style="top:-3px;position:relative;left:206px;height:57px;width:212px;text-align:center;" class="slidebox_progress">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
```

I have tried every conceivable variation on the indexing to try and get my section to work. Just cannot work it out.

All of the code is available http://www.leanproductions.co.uk/dev/

The Section I am trying to work in is at the bottom, Our Commitment.

Sorry there is so much code here, much of it probably not needed and as I say everything is available in the link.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. 
Luke

Comment: We see the code, but what are you trying to achieve? What does not work? What happens, what should happen instead?

Comment: Yes sorry, if you go to the Who We Are section and scroll through a couple of slides, you'll see the square at the bottom change class (to blue) these are then clickable links to the relevant slides.

Comment: Fir me it works ok. Could you say what is not working? And perhaps in which browser'

Comment: Chrome, Firefox and IE. The links in the top section 'Who We Are' do work. It is those I am trying to replicate. If you go to the 'Our Commitment' section near the bottom the links do not work. In fact at present when you scroll through the slides in the Our Commitment section the square navigation under the section disappears.